# ifdef and make: Invalid syntax in conditional

Tags: makefile, conditional-compilation

I am new in make. I was just trying to check whether the input given to the make is correct or not and if the user does not give any value, I'll just set it to '0'. The error encountered are as follows:

```
Makefile:11 *** invalid syntax in conditional. stop.
```

Below are some of the code that I've written:

```
ifndef farm_batch
 farm_batch = 0
endif

ifdef farm_batch \             #<--------- line 11 ---------
 ifneq ($(farm_batch),0) \
  echo "please input the correct value" \
 endif \
endif \

target:
    #do something here using $(farm_batch)
```

Note:

- When I remove the backlashes, I encountered additional errors which are:

  ```
   Makefile:13: *** missing seperator. stop.

   Makefile:255: *** missing 'endif'. stop.
  ```
- Example:

  ```
   make target farm_batch=9
  ```

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Make does not ordinarily take user input in the way you seem to have in mind. I'm not saying it *can't* be done, but the convention is to give Make whatever information it needs via the command line, like `make farm_batch=3`. You can give that variable a default value, and abort if the user provides an invalid value, but *accepting a new value during execution* is difficult and unconventional.

Comment: Hi there, sorry for the wrong use of words, what I meant by user input is just as you suggested where we give make the information that it needs to run the code. I'll edit question.

Comment: Did you search SO for `missing separator` (not `seperator`)? This is by far the top error message with make.

Answer (score 0):

So, you want make variable `farm_batch` to have a default value (`0`) and also to check that it indeed has this value, else print a message.

First of all, command-line variable assignments override Makefile assignements. So, for the default value simply add the following line to your Makefile:

```
farm_batch := 0
```

If you type just  `make`, the value of `farm_batch` will be `0`. If you type `make farm_batch=1` it will be `1`.

Next, don't mix make syntax and shell syntax (`echo` is a shell command). Shell syntax is for rules' recipes only (almost), that is, all lines in a rule that start with a tab. Everywhere else, use make syntax.

With GNU make, if you want to print a message and exit when `farm_batch` is not equal to `0`:

```
$ cat Makefile
farm_batch := 0

ifneq ($(farm_batch),0)
$(error please input the correct value)
endif

target:
<TAB>@echo "$(farm_batch): OK"

$ make
0: OK

$ make farm_batch=1
Makefile:4: *** please input the correct value.  Stop.
```

(replace `<TAB>` with a tab, and replace `error` by `info` or `warning` if you want a different severity level; with `error` make stops here and exits).

With another `make` that does not provide the `info`, `warning` and `error` functions you will have to put the printing of the message inside a recipe:

```
$ cat Makefile
farm_batch := 0

target:
ifneq ($(farm_batch),0)
<TAB>@echo "please input the correct value"
<TAB>exit 1
else
<TAB>@echo "$(farm_batch): OK"
endif

$ make
0: OK

$ make farm_batch=1
please input the correct value
exit 1
make: *** [Makefile:6: target] Error 1
```

(again, replace `<TAB>` by tabs). Note that you can also do the test with the shell, inside the recipe, instead of using make conditionals:

```
$ cat Makefile
farm_batch := 0

target:
<TAB>@if [ "$(farm_batch)" -ne 0 ]; then \
      echo "please input the correct value"; \
      exit 1; \
    else \
      echo '$(farm_batch): OK'; \
    fi

$ make
0: OK

$ make farm_batch=1
please input the correct value
make: *** [Makefile:4: target] Error 1
```